# interface compatible with Linq without a chance of multiple exection

Tags: c#, linq

I'm writing a very high amount of computed code that need a huge amount of linq stuff, so basically, a method do some stuff, pass to another method do a lot of other stuff using linq. and this is happening like 10k times.

to minimize the effort I created some extensions method that do the repetitive tasks. you can imagine something along this but more complicated

```
public static IEnumerable<int> IsBiggerThan2(this IEnumerable<int> input){
    return input.Where(x=> x>2);
}

public static IEnumerable<int> IsMod2(this IEnumerable<int> input){
    return input.Where(x=> x%2==0);
}

public static IEnumerable<int> IsMod3(this IEnumerable<int> input){
    return input.Where(x=> x%3==0);
}
```

my problem is when I use linq, the output is IEnumerable, this could cause to multiple execution, I also don't want to spam `.ToList()` at end of everyline.

```
var firstCalculation = someInput.select(x=> x+1);
var biggerAndMod2 = firstCalculation.IsbiggerThan2().IsMod2();
var biggerAndMod2And3 = firstCalculation.IsbiggerThan2().IsMod2().IsMod3();
var biggerAndMod2Plus1= biggerAndMod2.select(x=> x+1).IsBiggerThan2();

// and go on
```

after many lines it's becoming quite daunting and I wonder why there is no interface that share some characteristic between `List` and `Enumerable`.

I can pass `IList<int>` to `IEnumerable<int>` but not the vice versa and I need to cast it to list, I am looking for a workaround that I can accept linq result as my Input without needing to cast it to `List`

```
public static IEnumerable<int> IsMod3(this ISomething<int> input){
    return input.Where(x=> x%3);
}
```

I tried `ICollection`, `IReadonlyList`, `IList` but no luck, all need to cast to `List`

#### Update 1:

in describing the problem I made it over simplified, in those extension methods there are similar cases as what I showed with multiple use of the input arguments. in this way either I need to call `.ToList` on every input variable or before use of every extensions

Comment: How would you expect to be able to cast to a list without bypassing lazy evaluation? You could always make your specific methods call `ToList()` at the end, but personally I would suggest keeping it as it is, and being very deliberate about the points at which you wish to materialize the query.

Comment: Since your methods such as `IsMod3` take `IEnumerable<int>` and return `IEnumerable<int>` why do you need to use`ToList` at all? Show where you are required to use `ToList`.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "multiple execution"? When you use your result variables later on?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should never enumerate `IEnumerable` more than once. Just call `ToList()` on anything you plan to reuse multiple times.

Comment: @NetMage I made it too simple, in those methods there are similar cases as what I showed with multiple use of the input arguments.

Comment: `I wonder why there is no interface that share some characteristic between List and Enumerable.` I suspect `IReadOnlyList` is what you should be using.

Comment: `I am looking for a workaround that I can accept linq result as my Input without needing to cast it to List` Fundamentally you can't have what you want. If you want to be _100%_ sure you won't double enumerate you can't use `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 3):

The experimental [Memoize](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#memoize) method from MoreLinq may be what you want.